# Websphere - SOAP Service - Chaining Certificate Error using default SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, soap, https, websphere

I am working in a Websphere Application Server 8.5 environment and I am trying to integrate a new web service that expose using HTTPS protocol. Consider that, the first integration was done calling the service using HTTP protocol and consequently  I modified the code in order to manage the communication using SSL. Here below you can see the code that is managing the connection to this service, but at the moment I am receiving the error during the trust of certificate. I already checked that the right certificate is installed in WAS TreustStore.

CODE:

```
    GenericResponse response = null;
    AdaptiveAuthentication service = new AdaptiveAuthentication();
    AdaptiveAuthenticationInterface serviceInterface = service.getAdaptiveAuthentication();
    BindingProvider bindingProvider = ((BindingProvider) serviceInterface);
    Map<String, Object> requestCtx = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
    requestCtx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpoint);
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceInterface);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
    TLSClientParameters tls_cp = new TLSClientParameters();
    SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    if( sf instanceof SSLSocketFactory){
        tls_cp.setSSLSocketFactory((SSLSocketFactory) sf);
    }
    tls_cp.setUseHttpsURLConnectionDefaultSslSocketFactory(true);   
    tls_cp.setTrustManagers(getTrustAllTrustManager());
    tls_cp.setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom());
    tls_cp.setCipherSuites(Arrays.asList(((SSLSocketFactory) sf).getDefaultCipherSuites()));
    tls_cp.setJsseProvider((new com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider()).getName());
    requestCtx.put(JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY,tls_cp.getSSLSocketFactory());
    requestCtx.put(com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties.SSL_SOCKET_FACTORY, tls_cp.getSSLSocketFactory());
    http.setTlsClientParameters(tls_cp);
    if (type.equals(TMConstants.Type.ANALYZE)) {
        response = serviceInterface.analyze((AnalyzeRequest) request);
    } else if (type.equals(TMConstants.Type.NOTIFY)) {
        response = serviceInterface.notify((NotifyRequest) request);
    }
```

ERROR:

> org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Problem writing SAAJ model to stream
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:221) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:172) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271) ~[cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530) [cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463) [cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366) [cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319) [cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) [cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1283.analyze(Unknown Source) [na:na]
>       at xx.xxxx.xframe.xxx.common.log.txmon.CallbackHandler.call(CallbackHandler.java:110) [XXX.jar:na]
>       at xx.xxxx.xframe.xxx.common.log.xxxx.CallbackHandler.call(CallbackHandler.java:33) [XXX.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274) [na:1.7.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157) [na:1.7.0]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627) [na:1.7.0]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809) [na:1.7.0]
>   Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=***, O=***., C=IT is not trusted; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:261) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:213) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       ... 15 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=***, O=***, C=IT is not trusted; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.k.a(k.java:24) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.a(rc.java:19) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:308) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:338) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.cb.a(cb.java:558) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.cb.a(cb.java:187) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.t(bb.java:537) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:530) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.a(rc.java:797) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.h(rc.java:710) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.a(rc.java:815) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.rc.startHandshake(rc.java:408) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.c.afterConnect(c.java:142) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.d.connect(d.java:4) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1146) ~[na:1.7.0]
>       at com.ibm.net.ssl.www2.protocol.https.b.getOutputStream(b.java:49) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:170) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1282) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1233) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:183) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47) ~[cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89) ~[cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63) ~[cxf-api-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
>       at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
>       at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:259) ~[woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar:4.1.4]
>       ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=***, O=***, C=IT is not trusted; internal cause is: 
>       java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.a(f.java:44) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.b(f.java:123) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.util.e.a(e.java:3) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.zc.a(zc.java:163) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.zc.a(zc.java:130) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.zc.checkServerTrusted(zc.java:40) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.cb.a(cb.java:453) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       ... 37 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:410) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:256) ~[na:na]
>       at com.ibm.jsse2.util.f.a(f.java:99) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       ... 43 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by CN=***, O=***, C=IT is not trusted
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.(BasicChecker.java:111) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorImpl.java:176) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.myValidator(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:737) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:649) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.buildCertPath(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:595) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.engineBuild(PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl.java:356) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       ... 45 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.CertPathUtil.findIssuer(CertPathUtil.java:316) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       at com.ibm.security.cert.BasicChecker.(BasicChecker.java:108) ~[na:7.0 build_20170331]
>       ... 51 common frames omitted

Please help me to understand what I am doing wrong...
Thanks in advance

Comment: The error suggests to me that a WebSphere SSLContext is not being used, I'll take a guess that the JDK's cacerts file is used for trust here.   I don't see WebSphere's trust manager in the stack.    I don't know anything about TLSClientParameters(), but it seems your making a lot of changes to it that would wipe out WAS settings anyway like setting the trustmanager and messing with ciphers.   Is this code running a WebSphere server?

Comment: Apache cxf is not the jax-ws implementation used by traditional WAS, and support for "third party implementations" is limited ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html?pos=7 ).  Removing the cxf jars and using jax-ws spec api's, if that is practical, should let the WAS certificate management work.

Comment: A side note, If you are using 8.5.0.x, that is out of service, if that's the case you might consider moving to 8.5.5.x or 9.x.x, or WebSphere Liberty.  Liberty offers much-improved isolation for third party runtimes.